Why I can't delete label in every node?
I'm trying to delete names from all nodes using:
MATCH (n)
DELETE n:Name

But I get the error in Memgraph Lab that reads:
Query failed


Edges, vertices and paths can be deleted.

So how do I then delete label in every node?

The DELETE clause in is used to delete nodes and relationships, not labels or properties. If you want to remove a label from every node, you should use the REMOVE clause:
MATCH (n:Name)
REMOVE n:Name

